# Some web sites only load with 'www'

Tags: google-chrome

Using Chrome 47.0.2526.106 in x86-64 Debian testing.

Some web sites only load if there is the 'www' in the URL. E.g. https://instagram.com fails (never finishes loading - in fact, it never **starts** loading), but https://www.instagram.com works.

Other browsers (such as Firefox and Midori) on the same machine have no problems, so I assume it is not a network problem. I tried disabling all my extensions but does not help.

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your browser cache is corrupted - simply reset it.

Comment: I had tried this but initially it didn't work. Restarted Chrome (by killing all its processes) and now seems to work.